# Flip animation for multiple cards

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have four cards laid out in grid that I want to animate. I have successfully been able to animate 1 of them but when I try to add more of the animation javascript for the other cards not only do those cards not animate, but the first card that had successfully animated before no longer flips.

Here is the css for the card element:

```
.card-1-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.card-1-inner.is-flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Here is the javascript:

```
const card = document.querySelector('.card-1-inner');

card.addEventListener('click', function () {
    card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
});
```

When I try adding additional "const card" for .card-2-inner through .card-4-inner all flip animation breaks. I am very inexperienced, even more so with javascript.

Comment: Can you please add relevant HTML as well? Please add a code snippet if possible.

Comment: check this class .card-1-inner, try using a generic one for all the divs

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Code.

Good Luck.

```js
var base = document.querySelector('#cards');
var selector = '.card-1-inner';
base.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  let closest = event.target.closest(selector);
    if (closest && base.contains(closest)) {
    closest.classList.add('is-flipped');
  }
});
```

```css
.card-1-inner {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}

.is-flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="cards">
  <img class="card-1-inner" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
<title> Google Flipper </title>
<!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" media="screen" -->
<style>
 .cards {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
 }
 .is-flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }
</style>
</head><body>

 <div class="cards">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
 </div>
 <div class="cards">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
 </div>
 <div class="cards">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
 </div>
 <div class="cards">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
 </div>

<script>
var sel = document.querySelectorAll('.cards');
for (let x of sel) {
  x.addEventListener('click',
                     function(event) { x.classList.toggle('is-flipped'); } );
}
</script>

</body></html>
```